# Telegram telethon send query widget from another bot (Quizbot)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

In telegram app, when I type `@Quizbot quiz:ViioLbLq` in message box, I get a widget above message box, and when I click on that widget, a message gets forwarded with a 'via Quizbot'  text above.
When I do the same in telethon,

```py
client.send_message(someone, "@Quizbot quiz:ViioLbLq")
```

only the plain text is forwarded someone i.e. `@Quizbot quiz:ViioLbLq` .

I expect it to forward a full message with a 'via Quizbot' above. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`client.inline_query`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.bots.BotMethods.inline_query) for this:

```py
results = await client.inline_query('Quizbot', 'quiz:ViioLbLq')
# send the first result to some chat
message = await results[0].click('some group username')
```